# I can't shutdown my laptop using Ubuntu

Tags: shutdown

I am now using Ubuntu 13.10 with dual boot on window7.When I shutdown from ubuntu,my laptop restarts.I shutdown from window.Please solve my problem.Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shutdown from terminal.To do that run the below command in terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 0):

First install **laptop-mode-tools** by -

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

if it solves your problem well and good otherwise search dconf in dash open it and direct to app-indicator-session- suppress-shut-menuitem. as shown

[image: dconf]

save it and restart your pc then check if it works , if not then try-

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT as-

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

Restart and check , if nothing works then try [this script.](https://askubuntu.com/a/384823/192102)   well there are Four workarounds I have mentioned use them one by one only if one doesnt solves your issue . Till that you can use -

```
sudo shutdown now -p
```

for shut down and

```
sudo reboot
```

for restarting.

Comment: `/sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control` matches 184 entries on my system, so `gedit /sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control` seems a bit excessive.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have removed that . might be its different in each case.