# 13.10—shutdown impossible

Tags: 13.10, shutdown

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu on a new Desktop. I am using the following drivers from the image below.

[image]

I was searching half of the internet, found a lot of fixes for the »cannot shutdown« Bug but none of fixes worked for me. Whatever I do, the computer just restarts, no matter if I shutdown from terminal or by button. I tried tweaking the grub config, or the tricks with the dconfig editor, nothing works.

What else can I do to fix it?

Thanks in ahead!

well there are a lot of proposed fixes,

`sudo shutdown -P now`

[this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384757/cant-shutdown-after-installing-13-10)

tweaking `/etc/default/grub`,

by changing this line (adding acpi=noirq):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=noirq"`

followed by a `sudo update-grub`

and some more I do not find again.

**EDIT:**

I entered the BIOS and disabled `wake-on-lan`, now it shuts down, but I would appreciate a solution with which I could use the feature nevertheless.

Comment: Listing what you have tried will help in eliminating what not to try again and what you should try further.

Comment: When you say you've tried using the terminal, you mean `sudo shutdown -h now`, right?

Comment: jess, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sudo poweroff? Does it have the same problem?

If yes try this:

See /etc/init.d/rc and change concurrency=none. 
Reboot.

This may help.

Comment: well this one is new, gonna try it…

Comment: you mean CONCURRENCY=makefile to CONCURRENCY=none? Its line 72 in my case and the first appearance of CONCURRENCY in the whole file. Or somewhere else?

Comment: Set all instances of the concurrency=makefile to concurrency=none.

Answer (score 0):

First go to BIOS and change your power settings so computer won't start up after a power failure or from a remote command, includind wake-on-lan. Second go to Power Manager in Ubuntu and change settings for what 'power button' should do to 'shutdown', and see if there are other suspicious settings that may force your system to keep rebooting.

Once you're done you can install this program in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install qshutdown
```

Test it after install, and see if Qshutdown will be able to poweroff your computer.